# How to change files ownership in laravel via docker using powershell

Tags: laravel, powershell, docker, permissions, owner

I'm using docker on windows. After I created image from Dockerfile `docker build -t my-laravel-image` in my laravel project I tried to run it `docker run -p 8000:8000 my-laravel-image` but got the error in the browser `ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID`

After some digging I found that it is because `/storage` and `/vendor` doesn't have right permissions to write. However, I red on linux forum, that to to give permissions to everyone with `chmod 777` is bad so I should change owner with `chown`, however, I could find command which would do the job on Powershell, so I'm asking you for help

the tutorial I am following is https://www.techiediaries.com/docker-compose-laravel/

**EDIT**
Tried this `ICACLS "C:\Users\Dominykas\Projects\laravel" /setowner "administrator"` it succeded, but I get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
docker exec -it <your container> chown -R myuser:mygroup laraveldir
```